# Convert multiple array values include comma separated values into single array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array in java script like

Array [ no:"54", no:"55,57",no:"58",no:"60,61",no:"63"]

I want to result array like [54,55,57,58,60,61,63].

When i write code to make like this :

```
var bstr=[],i=0;
$.each( obj, function( key, value )
{ 
bstr[i++]=value.no;

}
alert(bstr);
```

Finally my array output is  [54,55,58,60,63]. Comma separated values are missing . I tried value.no.split(',') . It's returning the same array.

Comment: How is the data that you have actually arranged? Your description of it isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/55jq3x4s/

Comment: You are treating an array like an object., at least with how you have defined it above.

Comment: @SandeepNayak . Sorry. My array object is same like you described. I given in wrong format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the `array` you are talking about. I believe you need to have `array` of `objects`:

```js
var obj = [ {no:"54"},{ no:"55,57"},{no:"58"},{no:"60,61"},{no:"63"}];
var bstr=[],i=0;
$.each( obj, function( key, value )
{    
     $.each(value.no.split(','),function(index,item){
      bstr[i++]=item;
     });
     

});  // You missed closing this properly
console.log(bstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have array of objects. Using `concat` and `split` should give you the desired output.

```
var obj =  [ {"no":"54"}, {"no":"55,57"},{"no":"58"},{"no":"60,61"},{"no":"63"}]
var bstr=[],i=0;
$.each(obj, function( key, value )
{ 
    bstr = bstr.concat(value.no.split(","));
});
alert(bstr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8jn9pj5/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a jquery merge on 2 arrays (1 from the split and 1 from bstr).
https://jsfiddle.net/v4hoLes9/

```
var obj = [ {no:"54"}, {no:"55,57"},{no:"58"},{no:"60,61"},{no:"63"}];
var bstr=[];
$.each( obj, function( key, value ){ 
    bstr = $.merge(bstr, value.no.split(','));
});
alert("array length: " + bstr.length + "  values: " + bstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and a fancy little way to make the array with JSON.parse

```
var arr = [ {no:"54"},{ no:"55,57"},{no:"58"},{no:"60,61"},{no:"63"}];
var updated = arr.reduce( function(previousValue, currentValue){
     var val = JSON.parse("[" + currentValue.no + "]");
     return previousValue.concat(val);
}, []);
```

This results in an array of numbers, not strings like you will get with split()

Answer (score 0):

Mapped no's with join as comma separated pushing to the result array shown below

```js
let obj = [{
  "no": "54"
}, {
  "no": "55,57"
}, {
  "no": "58"
}, {
  "no": "60,61"
}, {
  "no": "63"
}]

let result = [];
result.push(obj.map(x => x.no).join(','));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```